# MongoDB Async Driver CallBack Error Handling

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous

We are evaluating the new MongoDB Async driver for writing to MongoDB asynchronously. And the fundamental problem that we are noticing is that on the CallBack, the full document is not available -

```
collection.insertOne(doc, new SingleResultCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Void result, final Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Inserted!");
        }
    });
```

Therefore in error handling situation or replay situation where if a document wasn't inserted, we would log the document. Is there nothing in the callback handler that would have the document logged?

Obviously we could marshall the callback handler into its own implementation but it is not a ideal solution for us.

Comment: did you find the answer to your question?